# Do stationary objects intoduce drag on closely passing moving objects

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, aerodynamics

Would it require more energy to drive down a narrow road lined with columns than a similar open road?

Would the columns intoduce drag on the passing vehicle, or effect its aerodynamics in any way?

Comment: Or through a narrow tunnel?

Comment: The moment you enter the tunnel would apply perhaps. My question is specifically considering columns because Ive seen vertical roadside windmills that utilize the wake of passing vehicles, and I want to know if there is any effect on the vehicle as it passes.